# How do I specify a closure that takes a reference and returns any type implementing a trait with the same lifetime as the reference?

Tags: rust

I need to tell the compiler that `F` returns something that implements `SomeTrait` with the lifetime `'a`:

```
trait SomeTrait {}

fn foo<P, Q, F>(func: F)
where
    Q: SomeTrait,
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a P) -> Q + 'a,
{}
```

But I get this error:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
 --> src/main.rs:6:33
  |
6 |     F: for<'a> Fn(&'a P) -> Q + 'a,
  |                                 ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

It is like it doesn't understand `Q + 'a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Q` is not a trait, it is a type; something like `T: Q + 'a` doesn't make sense.

If you try `F: for<'a> Fn(&'a P) -> (Q + 'a)` you'll get:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found type parameter `Q`
```

Your example actually parses like `F: (for<'a> Fn(&'a P) -> Q) + 'a` - and it should be obvious why that doesn't work.

Now to:

> I need to tell the compiler that `F` returns something that implements `SomeTrait` with lifetime `'a`.

Your function can't return different types depending on (passed) lifetimes apart from using those lifetimes for references or generic lifetime parameters. You could write a Rust compiler that simply ignores lifetimes completely, and if the original program was valid it would still do the same thing.

There is no way yet to specify type parameters that take generic parameters, for either lifetimes or types.

If there was, it could look like this:

```
trait SomeTrait {}

fn foo<P, for<'a> Q<'a>, F>(func: F)
where
    for<'a> Q<'a>: SomeTrait,
    for<'a> F: Fn(&'a P) -> Q<'a>,
{
}
```

Comment: *and it should be obvious why that doesn't work* — if things were obvious, then Stack Overflow wouldn't need to exist ^_^. If something is truly obvious, you don't need to state that it is obvious. If you do need to state it, then providing explanation or links to explanation is good.

Comment: Well yeah it's unfortunate then that compiler cannot do it. All I need to tell is that Q implements SomeTrait and is parametrized by some lifetime, so that I could use it in closure...

Comment: @user1682175 The planned Rust feature that will enable this is called [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md), although that RFC was accepted only a few months ago and it will probably be some time yet before there is an implementation. In the mean time, a workaround (when `SomeTrait` is object safe) is to have `F` return `Box<SomeTrait + 'a>`.

Comment: @trentcl Alas, the trait is not object safe in my case )

Answer (score 1):

Lifetimes can only be given to *references*. Changing the line to this works:

```
F: for<'a> Fn(&'a P) -> &'a Q
```

An object by itself does not have a "lifetime" as such - it lives until it is dropped. The borrow checker, however, must be informed of how long the object thst a reference points to lives relative to other referenced objects. *That's* where lifetimes come in.

Comment: Lifetimes are also used with [lifetime bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html#lifetime-bounds), which is what OP is trying to use here. They give a bound on all references contained in a type.

Comment: An object can have lifetime if it contains a member with a lifetime.